# Largest number in a finite set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, first-order-logic

Given a random set of numbers:

{1,2,8,4,16}

How do you give a logical definition for the largest number? I know how to say there *is* a largest number in the set S:

$$
\exists y \forall x \epsilon S \to y>x
$$

(or something to that effect) but not what it *is*. I'm looking for a numeric return, not a boolean.

Comment: It sounds like you want to define a *function* that takes in a finite set and spits out its largest element? Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: What about $\sup S$? For finite sets, it just spits out the maximum.

Comment: I don't know what a function would look like using logical terms, but perhaps. There's no reason the predicate I posted above can't be formatted in terms of a function either, right?

Comment: What do you mean by "in logical terms"? For example, is $\{(x,y)\:|\: x\in\mathcal{P}_{\mathrm{fin}}(\mathbb{N})-\{\varnothing\}\wedge y\textrm{ is a greatest element of }x\}$ the sort of thing you're looking for? If not, why not?

Comment: Given an array of numbers $[a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,\dots,a_n]$ the maximum can be written as $\max(a_0,\max(a_1,\max(\dots,\max(a_{n-1},a_n))\cdots)$ if you so insist.

Answer (score 1):

First-order logic conflates functions and relations when it comes to defining them. If $M$ is a structure and $f:M^n\rightarrow M$ is an $n$-ary function on $M$, we say $f$ is **definable in $M$** if there is some $(n+1)$-ary formula $\varphi(x_1,...,x_n)$ which defines the *graph* of $f$ - that is, such that for all $m_1,..., m_n, k\in M$ we have $$M\models\varphi(m_1,...,m_n,k)\quad\iff\quad f(m_1,...,m_n)=k.$$

In your case the relevant formula is "$x\in A$ and for all $y\in A$ we have $x\ge y$."

---

*(In the above I'm assuming that we're working with $2$-sorted structures, intuitively consisting of "sets" and "elements;" note that this is all still first-order unless I quantify over sets!)*